# Undefined reference question

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I'm getting this error in C++ and I really don't know how to get to the bottom of it:

> ```
> g++ proxy.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
> ```
>
> /tmp/ccUHa2s3.o: In function `main':
>   proxy.cpp:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to ``server::server(std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> > > const&, int)`'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have the following source code (which I copied off http://alexott.net/common/asio-proxy-async/proxy-conn.cpp.html):

```
//proxy.cpp:
#include "proxy-server.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        int thread_num=2;
        if(argc > 1)
            thread_num=boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]);
        ios_deque io_services;
        std::deque<ba::io_service::work> io_service_work;

        boost::thread_group thr_grp;

        for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; ++i) {
            io_service_ptr ios(new ba::io_service);
            io_services.push_back(ios);
            io_service_work.push_back(ba::io_service::work(*ios));
            thr_grp.create_thread(boost::bind(&ba::io_service::run, ios));
        }
        server server(io_services);   //apparently there's some error here?
        thr_grp.join_all();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}



//proxy-server.hpp:
#ifndef _PROXY_SERVER_H
#define _PROXY_SERVER_H 1

#include "common.h"
#include "proxy-conn.hpp"

#include <deque>

typedef std::deque<io_service_ptr> ios_deque;

class server {
public:
    server(const ios_deque& io_services, int port=10001);

private:
    void start_accept();
    void handle_accept(connection::pointer new_connection, const bs::error_code& error);

    ios_deque io_services_;
    ba::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};


#endif /* _PROXY-SERVER_H */


//proxy-server.cpp:
#include "proxy-server.hpp"

server::server(const ios_deque& io_services, int port)
    : io_services_(io_services),
      acceptor_(*io_services.front(), ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), port)) {
    start_accept();
}

void server::start_accept() {
    // Round robin.
    io_services_.push_back(io_services_.front());
    io_services_.pop_front();
    connection::pointer new_connection = connection::create(*io_services_.front());

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                           boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
                                       ba::placeholders::error));
}

void server::handle_accept(connection::pointer new_connection, const bs::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
        new_connection->start();
        start_accept();
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to fix this error?

---

#### Edit

I now get the following error:

> ```
> g++ proxy.cpp proxy-server.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
> ```
>
> /tmp/ccl3DHn7.o: In function ``server::handle_accept(boost::shared_ptr<connection>, boost::system::error_code const&)`':
>   proxy-server.cpp:(.text+0x250): undefined reference to ``connection::start()`'
>   /tmp/ccl3DHn7.o: In function ``connection::create(boost::asio::io_service&)`':
>   proxy-server.cpp:(.text._ZN10connection6createERN5boost4asio10io_serviceE[connection::create(boost::asio::io_service&)]+0x29): undefined reference to ``connection::connection(boost::asio::io_service&)`'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your titles and trailing your questions with redundant greetings/thanks/signatures. You are writing a question, not a letter, not a message board or "chat" post!

Comment: Why do you keep editing your question to break the formatting? Stop it.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the interface there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it cannot find the implementation of the `server` constructor. Have you written one which you do not show above?

**EDIT:** Ok, so you've written one, but you're not passing it to the compiler. You need to have `proxy-server.cpp` in your `g++` line.

**EDIT 2:** It is not enough to just compile the file containing `main` and include the header files. You need to provide all the cpp files to `g++`, or it will not be able to link your program.

```
g++ proxy.cpp proxy-server.cpp proxy-conn.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

Comment: Edited post to include proxy-server.cpp

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer. Sorry Nim; not your fault; it's just how the OP happens to have gone wrong!

Comment: @Tomalak, no need for apologies, I've upvoted this too... I did mention the not compiled and linked in thing, but not as explicitly as this...

Comment: @carlpett Thanks for that. I tried to compile, but now I'm getting another error. Please see my edited post. Many thanks,

Comment: I'm guessing that the `proxy-conn.hpp` header has a corresponding `proxy-conn.cpp`? In that case, you need to add that one as well: `g++ proxy.cpp proxy-server.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system`. If you have any other cpp files, you probably need to throw them on there too.

Comment: Well it's the same error isn't it. Looking at the code I would guess that you also need to include proxy-conn.cpp on the command line. You need to include **all** the cpp files you want to compile on the command line.

Comment: @carlpett - that's exactly what it was. I also had to add in a -lboost_regex for good measure! Many thanks!

Comment: @john - what does including all the cpp files together into one command do exactly?

Comment: @Eamorr, unfortunatly I don't think I could explain the process good enough, but some googling gave this link (http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/ch02.html), which seems to cover it quite well.

Comment: @Earnoor: It compiles them. You don't have to do it all at once. If you have a great many cpp files then you can compile them one at a time, and then link them together at the end. But one way or another you need to compile all your source code.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear from the error, you've declared the constructor for `server`, but the definition is not available (either not compiled and linked in, or not provided at all)

You need to define it in your `cpp` file.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply. But I'm including "proxy-server.hpp" in proxy.cpp. "proxy-server.hpp" has a class called "server"

Comment: Yes, there is a constructor declared called `server()`, but it's purely that, just a declaration. The implementation is not available...

Comment: @Nim: Confusing terminology in your comment, because the _functions_ are not defined. A function definition _is_ the function implementation. The class definition is essentially irrelevant; all it does here is contain the function _declarations_.

Comment: @Nim: Still confusing, because the class _is_ defined. I'd avoid talking about the class altogether.